# compare one file with three other files

Tags: java, list, file, compare, filereader

i write a bigger program in java for a poem analysis. Now i have one text file with a poem and three text files with words lists. I want to compare my poem with the three different word lists. So my program should say for example: this poem have three words from the list: MomentoMori, 0 words from the list vanitas and o words from the list carpe diem.

My Problem is: i know how to read files in java BUT i don´t know how to compare.

I thought that i should convert the text files into strings and then compare, but don´t know how? I did soemthing but it´s only compare the words of the first line from the poem with the first word from the word list.

Can anybody help me ? It´s only one percent from my program, but this step is very important.

Thank you all

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to be able to read from a list of words (from a text file) and see if those words exist within a poem (which is also in a text file)

Comment: Do you have any code that you've already written? It would help to see what you have done so far.